# Why is my local variable undefined when using RSpec's shared examples?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec2

I keep getting

`friend_or_open_profile_view_spec.rb:14:in 'block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method 'another_user' for #<Class:0x007f9d95f16668> (NameError)`.

I am able to use the another_user variable elsewhere through the spec just fine.  What am I missing?

Also, is there a better way to do this?  Profiles, depending on the user's status, will show different components.  I'd eventually like to move all those components into shared examples that can be called depending on the context.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "viewing a friend's or an open profile" do

  let(:user)         { Factory(:user) }
  let(:another_user) { Factory(:user) }

  before do
    sign_in user 
    User.stub!(:find).and_return(another_user)
  end

  context "when a profile is marked private" do
    it_behaves_like "a restricted profile", another_user
  end
```

Comment: Could you show your shared example? And does it work if you write `it_behaves_like "a restricted profile", Factory(:user)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered include_examples such that the shared examples are run in the current context.  This may be what I need...

Comment: `include_examples` is just an alias for `it_behaves_like_a`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "viewing a friend's or an open profile" do

  before do
    sign_in user 
    User.stub!(:find).and_return(another_user)
  end

  context "when a profile is marked private" do
    it_behaves_like "a restricted profile" do
      let(:user)         { Factory(:user) }
      let(:another_user) { Factory(:user) }
    end
  end
end
```